# How do I validate if the given input is an object in Python?

Tags: python, function, validation, object, types

I am creating a validation function that would verify if the inputs are objects.

I have no idea how to approach this. So, any help or suggestion would be highly beneficial.

Any search for object validation leads me to form validation in Django and that's not what I am looking for.

Comment: Could you show some starter code?

Comment: What does "if the inputs are objects" means ?

Comment: @RahulBharadwaj I don't have any. I have done validation for Strings and Lists but I don't know how to approach objects. I don't have any class definition also. I understand this is very vague information.

Comment: `return True` (everything passed to a function is an object in Python)

Comment: @hansolo I mean verification if the input can be classified as an object or not.

Comment: **Everything** is an object in `python` Could you clarify on what you mean by an `object` with a given context ? Like do you have some objects happen to be on the global namespace, and you want to check if the name you input is available in the global namespace ?

Comment: Please [edit] to provide sample inputs. What inputs are considered as "objects" and "not objects"? Do you mean objects as in instances of a specific class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you meant to validate objects of user created classes(because otherwise everything in python is an object), tried in Python3:

```
import inspect
def is_object(x):
  if isinstance(x, (int, str, float, complex)):
    print("Built-in class's object")
    return False
  elif hasattr(x, '__class__') and inspect.isclass(x) is False:
    print("Custom class's object")
    return True
  elif inspect.isclass(x):
    print("Class")
    return False
  else:
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use  `type()` to validate given input.

```
>>> a= 10
>>> type(a)
<class 'int'>

>>> class custom:
        pass
>>> a=custom()
>>> type(a)
<class '__main__.custom'>

>>>a="hello"
>>> type(a)
<class 'str'>

>>>a=[]
>>>type(a)
<class 'list'>
```

---

or else you can use `isinstance()` method.

```
>>>a=[]
>>>isinstance(a,list)
True

>>> a="hello"
>>>isinstance(a,str)
True

>>>a=122
>>>isinstance(a,str)
False

>>>a=122
>>>isinstance(a,float)
False
```